# What is the proper use of BIO_meth_new + BIO_get_new_index?

Tags: openssl

[From the OpenSSL 1.1.0 docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/BIO_get_new_index.html):

> ```
> int BIO_get_new_index(void);
> BIO_METHOD *BIO_meth_new(int type, const char *name);
> ```
>
> `BIO_meth_new()` creates a new `BIO_METHOD` structure. It should be given a unique integer `type` and a string that represents its `name`. Use `BIO_get_new_index()` to get the value for `type`.

But I cannot find any example code that actually uses `BIO_get_new_index()`! Even OpenSSL's own examples always do ad-hoc things like

```
// test/sslcorrupttest.c
#define BIO_TYPE_CUSTOM_FILTER  (0x80 | BIO_TYPE_FILTER)
[...]
method_tls_corrupt = BIO_meth_new(BIO_TYPE_CUSTOM_FILTER, "TLS corrupt filter");
```

([`BIO_get_new_index()` was added to OpenSSL on 2016-08-19, with no commit message and no tests.](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/8b8d963db5bb619fbada014f294fd09a855a2650))

In my own code, I've been using either `BIO_TYPE_FILTER` or `BIO_TYPE_SOURCE_SINK` directly, like this:

```
BIO_METHOD *meth1 = BIO_meth_new(BIO_TYPE_SOURCE_SINK, "StringBIO");
BIO_METHOD *meth2 = BIO_meth_new(BIO_TYPE_FILTER, "EavesdropBIO");
```

I have verified that `BIO_meth_new` does really return a new `BIO_METHOD*` in each case, so it's not naïvely using the supplied `type` as an index into a global table. Example:

```
BIO_METHOD *meth3 = BIO_meth_new(BIO_TYPE_SOURCE_SINK, "StringBIO");
BIO_METHOD *meth4 = BIO_meth_new(BIO_TYPE_SOURCE_SINK, "OtherBIO");
assert(meth3 != meth4);
```

However, it worries me that what I'm doing might be unsafe (I mean, even more unsafe than using OpenSSL to begin with ;)).  So I have two sub-questions:

- What could go wrong if I use `BIO_meth_new(BIO_TYPE_SOURCE_SINK, ...)`? In other words, why did OpenSSL decide to add `BIO_get_new_index()` in 1.1.0?
- If I should use `BIO_get_new_index()`, *how* should I use it? Is it intended to be `|`ed with the existing `BIO_TYPE_` macros, like this [below]? If I execute these lines repeatedly, aren't I "leaking" new indices? or does `BIO_meth_free` "free" the new indices as well as freeing the `BIO_METHOD` structure?

  ```
  BIO_METHOD *meth1 = BIO_meth_new(BIO_get_new_index() | BIO_TYPE_SOURCE_SINK, "StringBIO");
  BIO_METHOD *meth2 = BIO_meth_new(BIO_get_new_index() | BIO_TYPE_FILTER, "EavesdropBIO");
  ```

Comment: _"If I execute these lines repeatedly, aren't I leaking new indices?"_ — Self-answering: Yes, in that `BIO_get_new_index()` simply increments a global int, and nobody ever decrements it. It will eventually wrap around. However, I don't know if wrapping around is necessarily bad. No _resources_ are leaked; `BIO_get_new_index()` does not allocate memory or do anything other than incrementing that one global int.

Answer (score 2):

(I am not an OpenSSL developer, so take this answer with a grain of salt.)

> What could go wrong if I use `BIO_meth_new(BIO_TYPE_SOURCE_SINK, ...)`?

Nothing today, **BUT:** It is possible that a future version of OpenSSL could special-case the built-in BIO types.  The OpenSSL source code already special-cases certain types like `BIO_TYPE_SSL` and `BIO_TYPE_MEM`.  Generating your own BIO type future-proofs your code against that kind of shenanigans.

> If I should use `BIO_get_new_index()`, how should I use it? Is it intended to be `|`ed with the existing `BIO_TYPE_` macros [...]?

Yes, it is meant to be `|`ed with the flags `BIO_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR`, `BIO_TYPE_FILTER`, and `BIO_TYPE_SOURCE_SINK`.  The other types (e.g. `BIO_TYPE_SOCKET`) are true types, not flags.  This is an incredibly bad naming decision on the part of the OpenSSL developers.  Documentation-wise, [`BIO_find_type`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/BIO_find_type.html) mentions which "types" are secretly flags.

> If I execute these lines repeatedly, aren't I "leaking" new indices? or does `BIO_meth_free` "free" the new indices as well as freeing the `BIO_METHOD` structure?

Yes, you would be leaking type indexes.  BIO method type indexes are a finite resource that can be acquired but not released: `BIO_meth_free` does not "free" the indexes, nor does any other procedure I am aware of.  (You might not have thought of type indexes as a resource since `BIO_get_new_index` does not acquire other kinds of resources like memory or file handles, but I like to think of "resource" as a very general concept.)

In fact, the type indexes are an *extremely* limited resource.  The type flags start at `0x0100`, so the maximum type index you can create before interfering with the flags is `0x00FF` (i.e. 255).  Worse, indexes from `BIO_get_new_index` start at 128.  (It is possible that these bounds could be relaxed in future versions of OpenSSL.)

There is good news: once you have released a BIO method with `BIO_meth_free`, I suspect your application is free to re-use its index for a different BIO method.  However, you will need to build the free list of available indexes yourself.  It is probably not worth doing this; instead, write your application such that the number of BIO methods you need is a small compile-time constant.  Do not allocate new ones in a loop.  If you are writing a library, it is probably worth documenting how many BIO type indexes your library consumes.